# Can not querying inherited type properties in EF TPH

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, tph

Work on asp.net **mvc5** with **ef** version 6.1.3 and Unity repository .Say there is a model with a **base** type of **SmartDevice** and **three** derived types of **SmartRainbow**, **SmartRouter**, **SmartSwitch**. Like bellow:

```
private readonly IRepositoryAsync<SmartDevice> _smartDeviceRepository;
```

**constructor has bellow syntax**

```
_smartDeviceRepository = unitOfWork.RepositoryAsync<SmartDevice>();
```

**SmartDevice**

```
 public class SmartDevice : Entity
    {
        #region Primitive Properties
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int DeviceId { get; set; }

        public DeviceType DeviceType { get; set; }
        #endregion



        #region  Navigation Properties

        public virtual ICollection<DeviceStatus> DeviceStatus { get; set; }

        #endregion
    }
```

**SmartSwitch**

```
  public class SmartSwitch : SmartDevice
    {
        #region  Navigation Properties      
        public virtual ICollection<Channel> Channels { get; set; }              
        #endregion
    }
```

**SmartRainbow**

```
 public class SmartRainbow : SmartDevice
    {
        #region  Navigation Properties

        public virtual ICollection<RgbwStatus> RgbwStatuses { get; set; }

        #endregion
    }
```

By querying **SmartDevice** I get all entities my syntax is bellow:

```
var temp = _smartDeviceRepository.Query().Select().ToList();
```

problem is through every entity of above result will be of type **SmartRainbow** or **SmartRouter** or **SmartSwitch** I can not load  any single inherited type properties and navigation propreties.

Using the bellow syntax I failed to load the navigation property

```
var temp = _smartDeviceRepository.Query().Select().OfType<SmartSwitch>().ToList();
```

- Can  not load **SmartSwitch** property **Channels**?
- Can not use **include** after the **OfType** method?
- Why can not have **include** after the **OfType**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework 6 - inheritance and navigation properties on base class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24488653/entity-framework-6-inheritance-and-navigation-properties-on-base-class)